# JupyterLab not identifying hostname when launched

Tags: python, jupyter-lab, singularity-container

I'm trying to use a Singularity image to run a JupyterLab instance, but once the instance is started I'm unable to access it remotely because JupyterLab seems to fail to capture the name of the node it's running on.

Here's what I am doing for the sake of debugging. I'm accessing the image via Apptainer:

```
$ apptainer shell my_image.sif
```

Then I'm starting JupyterLab inside it:

```
Apptainer> jupyter-lab --ip 0.0.0.0
```

Here's part of the output of that command:

```
To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///user/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-397933-open.html
    Or copy and paste this URL:
        http://hostname:8888/?token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

When I try the same thing with other images, hostname above is replaced by the node name. With this particular image, though, JupyterLab seems unable to identify that name and put it on the URL.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Getting into the same issue when Using PyCharm remotely.